# C file comparison

Tags: c, string, comparison

I am trying to compare two files in C.  I am comparing each character until it gets to a (.  After the ( I don't care about the rest of the file until it reaches a new line.  Once the new line is reached I compare each character again until it reaches the (.  If there is a difference prior to the ( I want the program to let me know that the files are different.  If they are the same I want it to iterate through the file until it reaches EOF.  When the files match completely the program lets me know everything is good but getchar appears to grab some weird character (Ÿ) at the very end causing it to tell me there isn't a final match.

Also.  When I identify the ( it appears that the loop doesn't execute and it still flags the characters after the ( and tells me the match is bad even though I thought I should be ignoring it.  I hope this is clear and I look forward to any insight you may have.  thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

FILE *masterlist;
FILE *test;
char masterprc[12];
char testprc[12];
int i;
int j;

int n = 0;

//open authritative DB for proc calls
masterlist = fopen("masterlist","r");
//open strace of Shellcode
test = fopen("testprc","r");

//insures file properly opens
if (masterlist == NULL || test == NULL)
{
    printf("A file did not open\n");
    exit(0);
}else {         //if files both open then begin check

    do {        //loop iterates through the files comparing 
            //values

        j = getc(test);
        i = getc(masterlist);

        if (j == i) {
            printf("good\n");
            //putchar (j);
        } else if (j == '(') {
                while (j != '\n'){
                    //putchar (j);
                j = getc(test);
                    i = getc(masterlist);
                } 
        } else if (j != i) {
            printf("no good\n");

        }       
    } while (j != EOF);
}

fclose (masterlist);
fclose (test);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing C for this, you can just do it in the shell:

```
rpl="cut -d '(' -f 1"
diff --brief <($rpl masterlist) <($rpl testprc)
```

The idea is to take the text before any `(` and then just diff that content using the standard tools.

Comment: thanks for this.  Sadly this is just the first aspect of my code.  It has to be in C.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both lines the same before the `(` but different after, you're still running the check.
mainly because of the `} else if (j == '(') {`

Once you reach a `(` on `j`, if `i` equals `(`, you should keep running until the end of the line.

Your code isn't doing that

---

Let's debug your code a bit. I've added the cases of the conditions as follow:

```
   // -------- CASE 1 ---------------
    if (j == i) {
        printf("good\n");
        //putchar (j);

    // -------- CASE 2 ---------------
    } else if (j == '(') {
            while (j != '\n'){
                //putchar (j);
            j = getc(test);
                i = getc(masterlist);
            } 

    // -------- CASE 3 ---------------
    } else if (j != i) {
        printf("no good\n");

    }       
} while (j != EOF);
```

input:

master ->  `123(45`
test ->   `123(54`

j=`1`, i=`1` -> case 1 -> ok
 j=`2`, i=`2` -> case 1 -> ok
 j=`3`, i=`3` -> case 1 -> ok

And on the next run, here's your culprit:
 j=`(`, i=`(` -> you want case 2, but case 1 is executed.

You want case 2 here, to continue reading, but it won't happen,because case 1 is called since it comes BEFORE case 2 on the check conditions.

Comment: Shouldn't the while loop after identifying ( do exactly that?      else if (j == '(') {
                while (j != '\n'){
                    //putchar (j);
                j = getc(test);
                    i = getc(masterlist);
                }

Answer (score 0):

The weird characters are `EOF` printed as a char. You should check both files for `EOF` and probably also both files for left parantheses.